# Set values in $_POST in Yii2 on request recieved?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am writing a interceptor to validate request and decode data received from POST. After decoding data I have to set data to `$_POST` so that my all previous writer functionality will work as it is.

I have set values like below

```
$_POST['amount'] = $data['a'];
$_POST['currency'] = $data['c'];
```

I am able to get these variables using `$_POST` but these values are not accessible in `Yii::$app->request->post()`

**So my question is can I get these values by `Yii::$app->request->post()`**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post data is cached inside of `Request` component, so any changes in `$_POST` will not be reflected in `Yii::$app->request->post()`. However you may use [`setBodyParams()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#setBodyParams()-detail) to reset this cache:

```
Yii::$app->request->setBodyParams(null);

$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
```

Or just use `setBodyParams()` to set your data directly without touching `$_POST`:

```
Yii::$app->request->setBodyParams(['amount' => $data['a'], 'currency' => $data['c']]);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I was almost their

Comment: Can we partial change the request ? like: add other param, but still pass previous param ?

Comment: Late to the show, but maybe for others: yes it's possible, and I added an answer doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider refactoring your code a bit, especially if you are not the only person working on the project because artificially adding values to `$_POST` is just confusing and should be avoided, if possible. If I see a code that reads a variable from `$_POST`, I go looking for it being set on the frontend not somewhere in the controller.

You could make your interceptor do:

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
// or $post = _ $POST;
$post['foo'] = 'bar';
someNamespace::$writeData = $post;
```

Then when you want to access the data (assuming it doesn't always go through the interceptor and needs to be initialized when empty):

```
if (empty(someNamespace::$writeData)) {
    someNamespace::$writeData = $_POST;
}
$data = someNamespace::$writeData;
```

and read everything from that static variable instead of `$_POST`. It's neater and much more maintanable code, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend on the accepted answer of @rob006, in response to the comment below that by Budi Mulyo.

You can add to the post data by doing the following:

```
    $params = Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams();
    $params['somethingToAdd'] = 'value'
    Yii::$app->request->setBodyParams($params);
```

Still not sure if you want or need to do this, but it is possible :)